# How to expand html string in iframe src with data binding in Angular 10?

Tags: angular

I set my variable like:

**.ts**

```
html = getPage() // the function returns an html page
```

and I use it like:

**.html**

```
<iframe
    *ngIf="html"
    [src]="'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html | safe"
    style="border: 0"
></iframe>
```

But when `src` is set to the html string it's real html content inside is just document with empty head/body.

```
<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><head></head><body><p>hi</p></body></html>"></iframe>

// with content:

<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

How to tell this `iframe` to show it's `src` content after updating bound `html` variable?

Comment: try to use *ngIf

Comment: @moufed I do, didn't show it in code it doesn't solve it

Comment: <iframe
*ngIf="html"
    [src]="'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html | safe"
    style="border: 0"
></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not gonna work this way. The problem in it is that `src` attribute doesn't allow such big html content in it. So it's came up broken and iframe just doesn't work correctly showing an empty document.

The solution for this problem is to assign iframe's html from .ts.

In **.html** you have to bind a function on loading iframe:

```
<iframe
   #iframe
   (load)="onIframeLoad(iframe)"
></iframe>
```

Then assign it in **.ts** like this:

```
iframeDoc$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

//

onIframeLoad(iframe): void {
  this.iframeDoc$.next(iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow);
}
```

Then you can use it to assign your html to your iframe:

```
getIframeDoc(): Observable<any> {
   return this.iframeDoc$.asObservable();
}

yourFunctionForChangingHTML(): void {
  this.getIframeDoc().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(iframeDoc => {
     iframeDoc.open();
     iframeDoc.write(yourHTML);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked with the following pipe (see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-extrapolate)):

**safe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeResourceUrl, SafeScript, SafeStyle, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default:
                throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe [src]="'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html | safe: 'resourceUrl'" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

Comment: `safe` pipe used in my example and it doesn't work with it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can share in stackblitz?

Comment: sorry for the long answer. My code is quite complicated. Looks like the problem I have is in the html I'm trying to put into my iframe cause it works if I just hardcode some basic html like this I showed in my question.

Comment: It works using the pipe I shared in my answer?

Comment: it works with hardcoded html. But this it the same pipe I provided in my question. It still doesn't work in my project with my html

Comment: Share the [presumably] problematic html in your question. If possible, try to share the minimum html that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the content to `iframe` with `srcdoc` property. So, you will have:

```
<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8" [srcdoc]="html" style="border: 0"></iframe>
```